# XSL comparing and merging two XML stanzas

Tags: xml, xslt, merge, transform

I am trying to compare the following two XML stanzas and produce a third one.

1)

```
<Drive>
  <Folders>
    <Folder>
      <name>folder1</name>
      <Files>
        <File>
          <State>Writable</State>
          <name>file1</name>
        </File>
      </Files>
    </Folder>
  </Folders>
  <Files>
    <File>
      <State>Readable</State>
      <name>file2</name>
    </File>
  </Files>
</Drive>
```

2)

```
<Partition>
  <Directories>
    <Directory>
      <name>folder1</name>
      <Unix-File>
        <name>file1</name>
      </Unix-File>
    </Directory>
    <Directory>
      <name>folder-5</name>
      <Unix-File>
        <name>file-5</name>
      </Unix-File>
    </Directory>
  </Directories>
  <Unix-Files>
    <Unix-File>
      <name>file2</name>
    </Unix-File>
    </UnixFiles>
</Partition>
```

Now,

1) The resultant XML stanza should contain all the `Unix-file` and `Directory` elements which have the same name as the those in the first XML stanza and have a `State` of `Writable`.

2) Any matching folders which do not have any matching files should be omitted.

3) Here I assume the depth of the file structure is 2. i.e. the folders will not again contain folders.

So for the above scenario, the result should be

```
<Partition>
  <Directories>
    <Directory>
      <name>folder1</name>
      <Unix-File>
        <name>file1</name>
      </Unix-File>
    </Directory>
  </Directories>
</Partition>
```

I am using the following XSL file.

```
<xsl:if test="count(Drive/Folders/Folder) > 0">
  <Directories>
    <xsl:for-each select="Partition/Directories/Directory">
      <xsl:variable name="directoryName" select="name"/>
      <xsl:if test="../../../Drive/Folders/Folder[name=$directoryName]">
        <Directory>
          <name><xsl:value-of select="name"/>
          </name>
          <Unix-Files>
            <xsl:for-each select="Unix-Files/Unix-File">
              <xsl:variable name="fileName" select="name"/>
              <xsl:if test="../../../../../Drive/Folders/Folder[name=$directoryName]/Files/File[name=$fileName]">
                <xsl:if test="../../../../../Drive/Folders/Folder[name=$directoryName]/Files/File[name=$fileName]/State != 'Writable'">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:if>
              </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </Unix-Files>
        </Directory>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Directories>
</xsl:if>
```

The above XSLT works fine, except for requirement 2 above. i.e., when the files in a folder do not match, it should omit the folder too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may give this key based solution a try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="kFile" match="Files/File[State='Writable']" use="concat(../../name, '/' , name)"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="Directory">
        <xsl:if test="Unix-File[ key( 'kFile', concat( ../name, '/', name ) )]">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:for-each select="Unix-File[ key( 'kFile', concat( ../name, '/', name ) )]" >
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*" >
        <Partition>
            <xsl:if test="count(Drive/Folders/Folder) > 0">
                <xsl:element name="Directories" >
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Partition/Directories/Directory" />
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:if>
        </Partition>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xml>
    <Drive>
        <Folders>
            <Folder>
                <name>folder1</name>
                <Files>
                    <File>
                        <State>Writable</State>
                        <name>file1</name>
                    </File>
                </Files>
            </Folder>
        </Folders>
        <Files>
            <File>
                <State>Readable</State>
                <name>file2</name>
            </File>
        </Files>
    </Drive>
    <Partition>
        <Directories>
            <Directory>
                <name>folder1</name>
                <Unix-File>
                    <name>file1</name>
                </Unix-File>
            </Directory>
            <Directory>
                <name>folder-5</name>
                <Unix-File>
                    <name>file-5</name>
                </Unix-File>
            </Directory>
        </Directories>
        <Unix-Files>
            <Unix-File>
                <name>file2</name>
            </Unix-File>
        </Unix-Files>
    </Partition>
</xml>
```

It will generate the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Partition>
  <Directories>
    <name>folder1</name>
    <Directory>
      <Unix-File>
        <name>file1</name>
      </Unix-File>
    </Directory>
  </Directories>
</Partition>
```

The key "kFile" holds an entry for each file with State Writable in the form "[folder name]/[file name].
The Directory template check if there is an kFile key for  any Unix-File in this Directory.

Comment: Excellent. Exactly fits my requirement.